# Block Form1 until Form2 closes c#

Tags: c#, forms

In my code i from form1 launch form2 using `.Show()` .

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.show();
```

block `form1` until `form2` close and when `form2` closed continue my code.

Comment: What do you mean by "block' ? You mean open as a modal ?

Answer (score 4):

`.Show()` will show the new form you are displaying but it will enable you to go back and use the controls in the Main Form and `.ShowDialog()` wont allow you to access your main form unless its closed.

```
f2.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.showDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested that ways and don't worked but only below code worked:

```
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        this.Enabled = false;
        frm.Show();
        frm.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(frm_FormClosing);
        frm.Show();
    }

    private void frm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Enabled = true;
    }
```